# Rails Navigation Menu From Multidimensional Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multidimensional-array

I'm a web designer working in a rails/slim application. I'm not super familiar with rails though...

I'm tasked with building a navigation menu. I recall using a Jekyll, a ruby static site generator. I used to store my navigation data as yaml. This included the nav item labels and and link to paths.

I'd like to know if I can do the same in rails. For example, how could I traverse this array in my application helper controller and print out the nav in my view?

```
$navPages = [
  ["Home", "root_path"],
  ["Page A",
    ["Sub Page 1", "page_a_1_index_path"],
    ["Sub Page 2", "page_a_2_index_path"],
  ],
  ["Page B", "page_b_index_path"],
  ["Page C",
    ["Sub Page 1", "page_c_1_index_path"],
    ["Sub Page 2", "page_c_2_index_path"],
    ["Sub Page 3", "page_c_3_index_path"]
  ]
]
```

Note: "Page A" and "Page C" are only navigation parent items and not actual links.

Answer (score 0):

not the best way, just written by looking at the array you have given, and you will find a better way to do it for sure

```
<nav>
  <% navPages.each do |menu| %>
  <ul>
    <% flatten_menu = menu.flatten.drop(1) %>
    <% if flatten_menu.one? %>
      <li><%= link_to "#{menu[0]}", menu[1] %></li>
    <% else %>
    <li>
      <%= menu[0] %>
      <ul>
        <% flatten_menu.each_slice(2) do |sub| %>
          <li><%= link_to "#{sub[0]}", sub[1] %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It's in Slim syntax in case you aren't familiar with it.

First I changed the shape of my nav data:

```
$navPages = [
  [ 
    "Page A", 
    "page_a_index_path", 
    "" 
  ],
  [ 
    "Page B", 
    "",
    [
      [ "Sub Page 1", "sub_page_a_1_index_path"],
      [ "Sub Page 2", "sub_page_a_2_index_path"],
    ]
  ],
  [ "Page C", "page_c_index_path", "" ],
  [ 
    "Page D", 
    "",
      [
      [ "Sub Page 1", "sub_page_d_1_index_path"],
      [ "Sub Page 2", "sub_page_d_2_index_path"],
    ]
  ],
 ]
```

Then I iterated over it:

```
ul.menu
  - $navPages.each do |label, path, items|
    - if path != ""
      li
        = link_to label, self.send(path.to_sym)
    - else
      li.has-children
        = link_to label, "#"
        - if items != ""
          ul
            - items.each do |nlabel, npath|
              li
                = link_to nlabel, self.send(npath.to_sym)
```